# PokeAPI issue, can't get data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I am trying to use PokeAPI for educational purposes and I run this:

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry'
                //no uses el mismo nombre de argumentos
    https.get(url, function(resp) {
        resp.on('data', function(data){
            let datos = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(datos)
        })
    })
    res.send('lol')
})



app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on ${port} port!`))
```

And in the console I got this:

```
undefined:1
{"count":64,"next":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry?offset=20&limit=20","previous":null,"results":[{"name":"cheri","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry/1/"},{"name":"chesto","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry/2/"},{"name":"pecha","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry/3/"},{"name":"rawst","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry/4/"},{"name":"aspear","url":"https://pokea




SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\UdemyWeb\PokeProject\app.js:11:30)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:512:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:989:34)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:970:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

I've been asking around the internet, I even asked on their slack and got no responses, I think is the way I'm fetching the data from the API but I want to know why just with this API and not with others, I've tried with weatherAPI and D&D API and no problems at all.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the problem also occurs with others apis. Maybee the other responses were to small so they all arrived with the first chunk. I would recommend to use some `http` library like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). If you want to handle the chunks by your own, you have to aggreagte all the data and listen for the end event.

```
let data = '';
resp.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
});

resp.on('end', function() {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

Another good read i would recommend you is [5 Ways to Make HTTP Requests in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html)

Comment: nvm, it worked but I had to declare data as an empty string rather than `null`, thanks a lot for the explanation and help!

Comment: @AlejandroRdz Oops my fault. I fixed the sample. Your welcome!